# C# Continue execution of program after Exception is thrown

Tags: c#, exception, crash, execution, continue

How can I make the program continue its execution even if it crashes(Throws an exception).My current program works just fine if I manually press continue after the execution is thrown,so I want to make it continue the execution each time an exception is thrown.

Comment: I wish my software was like that... throwing exceptions and still work...

Comment: hahaa :D well,guess I'm just lucky..

Comment: What kind of program is it? Console app, winform, wpf, service, asp.net?

Comment: Handle the exception...

Comment: some extra background [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658708/ways-to-handle-exception), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2934716/578411) and [here](http://ericlippert.com/category/exception-handling/)

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but... Really?

Answer (score 3):

Use the try-catch statement.

```
try
    {
      // Your code. 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       // Handle the exception as you want or need.
    }
```

More information

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw(v=vs.120).aspx